# Can`t set column value to 0 (zero) in IF clause in php

Tags: php, variable-assignment, zero

Maybe if I dont know smth, but this one works:

```
$city = City::find(1);
$city->visible = 0;
```

This does not:

```
if ($city->visible = 0) {
}
```

This works

```
if ($city->visible = ***) {
}
// where *** - number, except 0 / letter
```

Why? Does it return false?

*My bad: thought it would assign value to variable in object.*

Comment: Because zero equates to false

Comment: The value of assignment expression is the value being assigned. So the first `if` evaluates to `if(0)`. You probably mistakenly didn't use `==` operator.

Comment: But I assign it to zero, don`t compare. What is the best way to do such check then ? (for all numbers except 0 it works flawlessly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expression

```
$city->visible = 0
```

Which evaluates to 0. So, you're essentially writing

```
if (0) { ... }
```

But `0` is a falsey value in PHP, so the IF block will never be called

---

Compare that to

```
$city->visible = 1
```

Which evaluates to

```
if (1) { ... }
```

`1` is a truthy value in PHP, so the block IF *will* be called

---

Per your comment, please see

```
$a = 1;      // this silently evaluates to 1; no visible output
echo $a = 0; // 0
echo $a;     // 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought by mistake that when I assign to zero - it stores 0 to variable in object

Comment: @mozg, it does store 0 to $city->visible. But assignment also has a "return" value. Please see my edit for additional clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Basic rules of PHP: the return value of an assignment operation is the value being assigned.

So when you do

```
if ($foo = 0) {
}
```

PHP will assign `0` to `$foo`, and then return `0` to the if() test. Since `0` is a false value, the if() test fails, and any code within it is not executed.

This is the exact same mechanism that allows

```
$foo = $bar = $baz = 42;
```

to work. The assignments are evaluated/executed right -> left, and each of the variables ends up having a value of `42`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if ($city->visible = 0) {}
```

is equivalent to:

```
$city->visible = 0;
if( $city->visible ) {}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if( 0 ) {}
```

which, of course, is equivalent to:

```
if ( false ) {
  // code that will never, under any circumstances, run. ever.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if ($city->visible == 0) { }

notice the == for comparison :?